# LEFT JOIN DEFAULT NULL VALUE

Tags: mysql, join, null

My query can be simplified as this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.* FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
```

Which `b` is from `group concat select (very dynamic column)`. Sometimes there are 3 columns in `b`, sometimes 10 columns depend on filtering.

What I want is something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, IFNULL(b.*,0) FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
```

I already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294117/mysql-select-all-check-all-columns-for-null-with-ifnull) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238604/ifnull-over-multiple-column) and the answer is always repeating per column. But I can't apply `ifnull` per column because I don't know what the columns are. Is there any other approach for replacing null values from left join?

All columns are of the integer type.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could have any number of columns from table `B`? If so, then you will need to dynamically create the SQL statement (by querying the `information_schema` table) and just wrap each column from `B` in your `ifnull(field, ifnullvalue)`.

Comment: It's not from specific table, it's generated table from query with dynamic column based on select. So i need all column selected from join to be replaced by 0 if they retun null value.

Comment: @SeptianPrimadewa the answer does not talk about any base table either. It advises you dynamically build this query, the same way you dynamically build the `B` derived table/view/query (whatever that is).